# HTML5 video only displaying poster on mobile

Tags: html

My video doesn't load on mobile , currently I'm checking on my Iphone and only the poster image displays. It only works for desktops or laptops. The website is https://zerogravitytables.com

I saw online that you need to have the attributes playsinline, muted , and autoplay but none of that is helping.

```
<video autoplay muted loop poster="{{cdn 'assets/img/mobile- 
  banner.png'}}" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="https://www.zerogravitytables.com/template/zero- 
      banner.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.zerogravitytables.com/content/BannerV2.webm" 
      type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://www.zerogravitytables.com/content/BannerV2.ogv" 
      type="video/ogg">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

I expected to see the video autoplay on mobile but it wont even load and only displays the poster image.

Comment: Lots of mobile browsers ignore the `autoplay` attribute to save the users mobile data. You may need to check for the platform and display controls for mobiles.

Comment: You can not actually since its been disabled across all mobile platforms... You should convert the video to gif and serve gif on mobile platforms...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I really appreciate it!